# Failure to set Ace Editor used via the ui-ace directive into readOnly mode

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ace-editor

The ui-ace library I'm using: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace

The markup:

```
<div class="ace-directive" 
     ng-model="template.value" 
     style="width: 100%; font-size:15px;" 
     ui-ace="{
      useWrapMode : true,
      showGutter: true,
      mode: ace.theme,
      onLoad : ace.loaded,
      onChange: ace.changed
     }">
</div>
```

The controller code:

```
$scope.ace.loaded = aceLoaded;
function aceLoaded(editor){
        editor.setReadOnly(true);
    }
```

Note: The actual logic for setting the editor's state is conditional on a variable and not literally a boolean 'true'.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Making the editor readonly is exposed through a specific html template attribute. From the docs:

```
<div ui-ace readonly="{{checked}}"></div>
```

You can change the value of `$scope.checked` in your controller or then just toggle `checked` to something truthy elsewhere in your html template.

If you want to change the readonly status like you're trying to in the `aceLoaded` function, you need to call setOptions:

```
function aceLoaded(editor){
  editor.setOptions({
    readOnly: true
  });
}
```

... but this also requires you to keep a reference to the editor around to change the status later on. A scope variable like in the first case is probably easiest, but of course it doesn't offer any other functionality like the latter would, if you actually need it.

Comment: Okay, scratch that. Turns out it makes readOnly always! Isn't reading the truthyness of the expression I pass in.

Comment: I have this working successfully like the first example. This is using FF and Chrome, I haven't tested other browsers, but it's probably not a browser problem. Can you try either the AngularJS Batarang or ng-inspector extension in Chrome(ium)? That will allow you to read your scope variables to make sure they're what you expect. Alternatively, share some code, there might be something that you're overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-readonly:

```
<div ui-ace 
    ng-readonly="checked">
</div>
```

where `checked` is a scope variable.

Comment: Comes a few months too late and I'm not inclined to test this out just now since the project has been trashed, but thanks anyway...